# Problems with spiderweb graph from Highcharts in R

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts

I've got some problems using spiderweb graphs from rCharts. Graph is not displaying as it should be. Any ideas ?

```
library(shiny)
    library(rCharts)
    runApp(
      list(ui = fluidPage(
        tags$head(tags$script(src = "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"),
                  tags$script(src = "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"),
                  tags$script(src = "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"),
                  tags$script(src = "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js")
        ),
        titlePanel(""),
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("Highcharts Spiderweb",
                   showOutput("Spiderweb","highcharts"))
        )
      ), 
      # server side
      server = function(input, output){
        output$Spiderweb <- renderChart2({
          plot <- Highcharts$new()
          table = data.frame(id = c("a1","g3","k5","y9","z11"),
                             value = c(252,345,421,189,236))
          plot$chart(polar = TRUE, type = "line")
          plot$xAxis(categories=table$id, tickmarkPlacement= 'on', lineWidth= 0)
          plot$yAxis(gridLineInterpolation= 'polygon', lineWidth= 0, min= 0)
          plot$series(data = toJSONArray2(table[,c("id","value")], json = F, names = F),
                      name = "Series", pointPlacement="on")
          plot
        })
      }
      )
    )
```

[image]

Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the tags$head, `showOutput` will load them, right now the Highcharts libs are being loaded twice, and highcharts error 16 is raised.

Also, when you assign the series, you don't need the JSON array, `data=table[,"value"]` works fine.

Here is the modified code:

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)
runApp(
        list(ui = fluidPage(
                titlePanel(""),
                tabsetPanel(
                        tabPanel("Highcharts Spiderweb",
                                 showOutput("Spiderweb","highcharts"))
                )
        ), 
        # server side
        server = function(input, output){
                output$Spiderweb <- renderChart2({
                        plot <- Highcharts$new()
                        table = data.frame(id = c("a1","g3","k5","y9","z11"),
                                           value = c(252,345,421,189,236))
                        plot$chart(polar = TRUE, type = "line")
                        plot$xAxis(categories=table$id, tickmarkPlacement= 'on', lineWidth= 0)
                        plot$yAxis(gridLineInterpolation= 'polygon', lineWidth= 0, min= 0)
                        plot$series(data = table[,"value"],
                                    name = "Series", pointPlacement="on")
                        plot
                })
        }
        )
)
```

Gives this:
[image]

Comment: I believed spiderweb chart was not in the original package. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Would it be possible to have outer value of each id based on the value of that id? That is useful if you add multiple series you want to compare and when the ranges of those variables vary greatly. If a1 has now a corresponging value of 10000 you can't get information from it. If it is unclear: change the 252 to 10 000 and you'll get my point.