# rCharts spiderweb plot rendered in Shiny as line plot

Tags: shiny, rcharts

The spiderweb plot created using the code below renders well within the Rstudio plot panel as shown below.

[image]

However, it appears as line plot when rendered using Shiny as below.
[image]

```
library(rCharts)

shinyServer(function(input,output){
  output$plot <- renderChart2({

    plot <- Highcharts$new()
    table = data.frame(id = c("a1","g3","k5","y9","z11"),
                       value = c(252,345,421,189,236))
    plot$chart(polar = TRUE, type = "line")
    plot$xAxis(categories=table$id, tickmarkPlacement= 'on', lineWidth= 0)
    plot$yAxis(gridLineInterpolation= 'polygon', lineWidth= 0, min= 0)
    plot$series(data = toJSONArray2(table[,c("id","value")], json = F, names = F),
                name = "Series", pointPlacement="on")
    plot
  })
})
```

HTML:

```
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="shared/shiny.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="shared/shiny.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="plot" class="shiny-html-output rChart highcharts" style="width: 4px; height: 60px"></div>
<body>
```

Any ideas to have the plot displayed in Shiny as it should be? The plot is rendered ok according to [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282646/problems-with-spiderweb-graph-from-highcharts-in-r) but the difference is that in my case the UI is built entirely using HTML while they use ui.R instead.

Answer (score 0):

What is needed is to add

```
 <script src="js/highcharts-more.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and it now works.